# JavaScript stopped working when changing css

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

after working with my css for about an hour, my javascript validation for my html form suddenly stopped working. Really can't figure out what went wrong since i haven't touched my html or js files at all..

```
function validateForm()
{
var validName = document.forms["myForm"]["namn"].value;
var validEmail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var validMsg = document.forms["myForm"]["medd"].value;

if (validName == null || validName == "")
{
    alert("Please enter a name."); 
    return false;
}

if (validEmail == null || validEmail == "" validEmail.trim() == null)
{
    alert("Please enter a valid Email.");
    return false;
}

if(validName.trim() == null || validName.trim() == '')
{
    alert("inga mellanslag!");
    return false;
}

if (validEmail.indexOf('@') === -1)
{
    alert("enter valid email");
    return false;
}

if(validEmail.indexOf('.') === -1)
{
    alert("enter valid email2");
    return false;
}

if(validMsg.trim() == null || validMsg.trim() == '')
{
    alert("enter valid message");
    return false;
}
}


<script src="main.js"> </script>
    <div class="kommentar">
        <form name="myForm" action="db.php" method="post">
            <p>First name:</p>
            <input class="rutor" type="text" name="namn"><br>
            <p>Email:</p>
            <input class="rutor" type="text" name="email"><br>
            <p>Message:</p>
            <textarea class="meddelande" type="text" name="medd" ></textarea>           
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="knapp" value="Kommentera" onclick="return validateForm()">Kommentera</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What does it say in the Javascript console? Isn't it complaining about a syntax error? That Javascript code could never have worked, the CSS is irrelevant.

Comment: BTW, `validMsg.trim() == null` can NEVER be null. It will always be a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line

```
if (validEmail == null || validEmail == "" validEmail.trim() == null)
```

to

```
if (validEmail == null || validEmail == "" || validEmail.trim() == null)
```

and tell me if that helped